# Signalr update claims

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

I have an signalr hub with web socket transport and initially it is allowed for unauthenticated users to connect. What I am trying to achieve is to have events to be pushed from the hub to connected clients and user specific events only if there is an authenticated user on that connection.

The hub also exposes some methods that need authorization but the problem is that once hub connection is made there is no way to update current user/claims on that connection.

I am using Jwt Bearer tokens for authentication but I guess the authentication scheme don't play a role.

Comment: Can you post the relates code about configuring the JWT authentication and update the user/claims? Whether you are using Asp.net core Identity to manage claims or not? Besides, what do you mean about " there is no way to update current user/claims on that connection"? Based on my understanding, when access the protected page, it will redirect to the login page, and the claims will be added after login, then we can get the user claims from the `HttpContext.User`.

Comment: Say we have a signalr connection without any authentication, at later point we get the jwt token by using web api and after that this token needs to be used on existing connection, based on what I can find on web signal r will only keep initial authentication (claims) on existing connection and requires you to disconnect and reconnect again which is not desirable.